# How to interpret binary instruction using the intel manual

Tags: ghidra, x86-64, intel

OK. So I am really trying to figure out how to use the "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual" for myself, since it seems like the authoritative source for x86(_64) machine code.

I am looking at a program in Ghidra (specifically, a dynamically linked .so file to the program I actually care about). File info for the .so file:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

I come to the following instruction in Ghidra:

```
ff 25 de ad be ef  --- deadbeef being a substitute for the real bytes.
```

I have Ghidra set up so that I can right click on the instruction and go to the relevant page in the processor manual, which brings me to the JMP reference (p.590 in the version of the manual I have). Cool.

From looking through the options there, I find the `ff` opcode rows that correspond to the instruction I am looking at. Further, I know that my `ModR/M` byte is `25H` which corresponds to `MOD = 00B`, `REG = 100B` and `R/M = 101B` so I know that this narrows it down to the `FF /4` rows in the `JMP` instruction description table. But how do I know if it is referring to `JMP r/m16` or `JMP r/m32` or `JMP r/m64`? Also what is the difference between those three? And further, I know from looking at tables 2-1 through 2-3 (combined with how Ghidra interprets the instruction) that `de ad be ef` actually ends up being a disp32 that gets added to the index. But how would I have known which table to reference in tables 2-1 to 2-3, and how does that information correspond to choosing between `JMP r/m16` or `JMP r/m32` or `JMP r/m64`?

Comment: The `r` in `r/m16` et al means **r**egister. `m16`/`m32`/`m64` means **m**emory, either 16- 32- or 64-bit address width. If mod is 11, `r/m` is interpreted as `r`, otherwise `m`. If the CPU were operating in 16-bit mode, only `ff 25` would contribute to the instruction, resulting in `jmp [di]` followed by four gibberish bytes. For differentiating 32/64, it depends on the operating mode -- it's probably going to be 64-bit based on your .so info and question tags.

Comment: @smitelli please post this in the answer box. comments should be used for clarifications, not for answers